# ¿Cómo puedo programar una UDF que trabaja con rangos?

Tags: vba

Las entradas de la UDF son: ingresos y años.
Debe tomar el logaritmo base 10 de los ingresos y con esos nuevos valores calcular la pendiente utilizando los años. Finalmente, debe devolver el valor: 10 ^ pendiente - 1.
He estado tratando de dar con la solución con el siguiente código:

```
Public Function CAGR_Log10(revenues As Range, years As Range)
Dim celda As Range
Dim log As Range
Dim pendiente As Double


For Each celda In revenues
log = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(celda.Value)
Next celda

pendiente = Application.WorksheetFunction.Slope(log, years)

CAGR_Log10 = 10 ^ pendiente - 1

End Function
```

Entonces, lo que necesito es, por ejemplo: dado revenues = 1,2,3,4,5.... y years = 2010, 2011, 2012..., tomar log = log(1), log(2), log(3), log(4), log(5)... y luego con log y years calcular la pendiente. Es decir, primero requiero modificar todos los valores del rango revenues tomando su logaritmo en base 10.

Comment: Cuál es el fallo? No obstante, `log = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(celda.Value)` no sé si ahí quieres ir acumulando datos o sólo el último que salga, en cuyo caso no tendría sentido hacer un bucle, sólo coger  `Application.WorksheetFunction.Log10(revenues.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))` de lo contrario, debes añadir `log = log + ...`

Comment: Hola, lo que necesito es, por ejemplo: dado revenues= 1,2,3,4,5.... y years= 2010,  2011, 2012..., tomar log=log(1), log(2), log(3), log(4), log(5)... y luego con log y years calcular la pendiente.

Comment: PEro cual es el problema? deberias guardar cada logaritmo en algun lado..

Comment: Eso es lo que quiero, que guarde los logaritmos, pero el código me da error ¡#VALOR!

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.